# C# List of Object not Ordering by several objects down

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a `List<CableList>`. `CableList` has a property called `Location` which is an object, which has a property called `Facility`. `Facility` is also an object.

I am trying to order by `Facility.FacilityTitle`. `FacilityTitle` is a string.

I am doing

```
Runlist.OrderBy(x=> x.Location.Facility.FacilityTitle)
    .Skip(variable)
    .Take(Paginationnum)
    .ToList();
```

This returns the list but it is not ordered by `FacilityTitle`.

Comment: What is the output of that `OrderBy` function?

Comment: Do you assign that to anything?  It will create a new list.

Comment: Did you call your list object the same as the class it is an instance of? Are you sure Location and Facility aren't null? If this is Linq to Sql (EF), Include should be added to retrieve Location and Facility too.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

When you using ToList() method it convert your sequence to not oredered list.
Use this code instead:

```
IEnumerable<CableList> list=Runlist.OrderBy(x=> x.Location.Facility.FacilityTitle)
    .Skip(variable)
    .Take(Paginationnum);
```

Comment: "it convert your sequence to not oredered list" - I'm not sure what you mean by this. Calling ToList just converts an IEnumerable to a List object. The ordering won't change so if the items were ordered before they will be in the same order after...

Comment: U know I feel like an idiot, it has been a hell of a week

Answer (score 1):

Here example with Linq to objects. The `ToList` really didn't change the ordering of the list.

```
List<CableList> Runlist = new List<CableList>
{
    new CableList { Location = new Location 
    { Facility = new Facility { FacilityTitle = "titel3"  }}},
    new CableList { Location = new Location 
    { Facility = new Facility { FacilityTitle = "titel2"  }}},
    new CableList { Location = new Location 
    { Facility = new Facility { FacilityTitle = "titel5"  }}},
    new CableList { Location = new Location 
    { Facility = new Facility { FacilityTitle = "titel1"  }}},
    new CableList { Location = new Location 
    { Facility = new Facility { FacilityTitle = "titel9"  }}}
};

System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Before order:");
foreach (var itm in Runlist)
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(itm.Location.Facility.FacilityTitle);

var orderedResult =  Runlist.OrderBy(x => x.Location.Facility.FacilityTitle)
    .Skip(1)
    .Take(4)
    .ToList();

System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("After order:");
foreach (var itm in orderedResult)
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(itm.Location.Facility.FacilityTitle);
```

---

*Output:*

```
Before order:
titel3
titel2
titel5
titel1
titel9
After order:
titel2
titel3
titel5
titel9
```